# How to create a new auth user inside supabase database function?

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

I want to write a plpgsql function that recieves an email and returns an auth.users.id if the user with that email exists or creates a new user and returns it's id.

I have this function that returns an existing user, but I am unsure if there is a way to trigger the user creation flow.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_user_by_email(email text)
RETURNS uuid AS $$
DECLARE
    user_id uuid;
BEGIN
    SELECT id INTO user_id FROM auth.users AS usr WHERE usr.email = get_user_by_email.email;
    RETURN user_id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER;
```

Comment: For creating auth users, you should use the edge functions instead of the database function. https://supabase.com/docs/guides/functions

Comment: Thank you, that's more or less what I am currently doing: the edge function calls the db function to get the user; if there is no user, the edge function creates a user. I was trying to save time on a round trip.